# Relative layout is shifing when progress bar running

Tags: android, xml

I have login layout,when  progress bar executes the layout shifts, This my xml code please check my code.And help me to rseolve.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:flatui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

       >




    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Mobile Number"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"

            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/mnum"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            style="@style/EditBoxStyle"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:maxLength="10"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_design"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            style="@style/EditBoxStyle"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/pswrd" />

        <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:id="@+id/loginBtn"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="235dp"
            flatui:fl_touchEffect="fl_ripple"
            flatui:fl_theme="@array/grass"
            flatui:fl_blockButtonEffectHeight="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp" />




        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/frgtext"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Forgot Password?"
            android:autoText="false"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:textColor="#ff666666"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />








    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

           <!-- <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/loginBtn"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               />-->
            <com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
                android:id="@+id/loading"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"

                wheel:matProg_barColor="#ff5cb85c"
                wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate="true" />


            </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity = "bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       >
        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TableRow>
                <Button
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/ntregtext"
                    android:text="New Registration"

                    android:textColor="#ff666666"
                    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


                <Button
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:text="Check our offers"
                    android:textColor="#ff666666"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Attached Images before progress bar and after progress bar running................................................

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Table layout used Liner layout given weightsum as total item in horizontal.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity = "bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
   >
   <!-- <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TableRow>-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">
            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/ntregtext"
                android:text="New Registration"

                android:textColor="#ff666666"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <Button
                android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="-5dp"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:text="Check our offers"
                android:textColor="#ff666666"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
       <!-- </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>-->
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sad"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```